# How do i write in a file the data from GAPI?

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite, google-analytics-api

I´me using GAPI (Google Analytics PHP Interface) to get the most searched keywords in my website. This code works ok

```
$ga->requestReportData(id, array('searchKeyword'), array('searchUniques'),array('-searchUniques'),null,null,null,1,12  );


foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
 echo ' '. $result .'   '.$result->getSearchUniques().'<br/> ' ;
}
```

But I would like the output to be written on a file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('results.txt', 'w');
$ga->requestReportData(id, array('searchKeyword'), array('searchUniques'),array('-searchUniques'),null,null,null,1,12  );


foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
     fwrite($fp, " ". $result ."   ".$result->getSearchUniques()."\n"); 
}


fclose($fp);
```

Don't forget to create a file named `results.txt` (or whatever name you want) and chmod it to 777.

Answer (score 0):

```
$savefile='/your/dir/to/use/ga.txt';

$fh=fopen();
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
   $line_to_save = ' '. $result .'   '.$result->getSearchUniques()."\n";
   fputs($fh,$line_to_save);
}

fclose($fh);
```